# Enable user to change status number in database with a button

Tags: php, database, button, if-statement

I have a database table, within the table i have `id`, `content` and `status`.

The table is for a to do list, where the user can type in to-do `items`, the items then be saved to the `content` of the database, i can change the status of the content to **1,2** and **3** from the database which then changes the color of the text, this is for done, not done and partially done.

However I want to insert buttons so that the user can change this, so they would be changing the status from the front end, with a button saying done etc, but what it would be doing in the back end is changing the number of the status value, any ideas?

```
// update the list view
for (var i=0; i< res.length; i++){
     $("<li/>", {"id": res[i].id, "text": res[i].content + res[i].status, "class": 'status-' + res[i].status}).appendTo(todo.list);
}
```

This is the code that changes the color of the item, i have added a '.status-' class to my styling.

Here is ajax that is within my todo.js

```
todo.addList = function (text){
$.ajax({
    url: 'server.php',
    method: 'GET',
    data: 'op=addList&content='+text,
    dataType: "json", // response as json
    error: function(res){
        todo.updateInfo("Failed to add new entry");
    },
    success: function(res){
        todo.updateInfo("New Entry added");
        todo.addView(res);
    }
});
```

Comment: two things, post your code, and what does UIButton has to do with php?

Comment: are you familiar with processing forms in php? If you have never done this before, i suggest learning this first.

Comment: Deleted tag UIButton no need for that.

Comment: Was meant to be button, sorry.

Comment: edited, with the code.

Comment: I need it so that there are 3 buttons and each button is representative of the status so it would be either 1,2 or 3

Comment: @user3298400 do you have any back end code? if you don't are you using any kind of framework?

Comment: I have a server.php file which includes all the queries and functions?

Comment: You'll probably want to read up on `ajax`

Comment: agree, look at up at ajax, and send all does values in a `$.ajax` post and update the data after validation... if you post what you have is easy to anyone here to help in how to do it

Comment: I have edited the code to show you a sample piece of ajax that is within my JavaScript file, is this something that I would need to do for the buttons?